# Series-Convergence and divergence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does this series converge or diverge?
>   $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^{1/2}}{n-1}$$

I think it is divergent. This is how I proceeded: Divide numerator and denominator by $n^{1/2}$ and it is greater than or equal to $\frac1{n^{1/2}}$  and since this is divergent, by comparison test, given series is divergent. Am I done?

Comment: What do you think ? What did you try already ?

Comment: I think its divergent. This is how i proceeded divide numerator and denominator by n^1/2 and it is greater than or equal to 1/(n)^1/2 and since this is divergent..by comparison test, given series is divergent...am I done?

Comment: You can use the limit comparison test, for instance.

Comment: Please post your work. Otherwise, there are big chances that the question will be closed for missing context.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  yes. I did.Thank you

Comment: Better ! And, by the way, welcome to MSE which is a fantastic site. Cheers :-)

Comment: Here be the formatting tips for the future.  Use them wisely : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You can use the comparison test and the fact that $$\frac{n^{1/2}}{n-1} > \frac{1}{n-1} > \frac1n$$

In your question, you used the comparison test with $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$. This also works, but I would write out a little more specifically why the terms are larger than $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$, like I did above with $\frac1n$.

Answer (score 0):

Limit Comparison Test + Integral Test:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^{1/2}}{n-1}\implies\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n^{1/2}}n=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n^{1/2}}\implies\int_2^\infty x^{-1/2}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

We can see that by D'Alembert's ratio test the limit becomes 1 and thus the test fails. Then we use Raabe's test and after some manipulation we get the limit as 0.5 when n tends to infinity. Thus the series is divergent.
 And also the method you have used is perfectly right as the terms of the series are less than n^0.5 for all n>1 .

Answer (score 0):

*Simplest (as often):* Use equivalents, since it is a series with positive terms. The general term is
$$\frac{n^{1/2}}{n-1}\sim_\infty\frac{n^{1/2}}{n}=\frac1{n^{1/2}},$$
which is a divergent *Riemann series*.